# Why does urllib.parse.quote not convert / to %2F?

Tags: python

I want to convert classic URL `'http://bla/ble/bli'` to `'http:%3A%2F%2Fbla%2Fble%2Fbli'`.

I tried with urllib library, but it only converts `:` to `%3A`:

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote('https://bla/ble:bli')
#https%3A//bla/ble%3Abli
```

And I can't find a function that converts `/` to `%2F`.

Comment: What are you planning to use the quoted value for? Please give a little more context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urllib#url-quoting) for urllib.parse.quote? Do you see the part about the `safe` parameter, and its default? Can you think of a way to use this to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `/` is considered safe. Pass `safe=''` to `quote`

```
quote('https://bla/ble:bli', safe='')
# 'https%3A%2F%2Fbla%2Fble%3Abli'
```

According to the docstring, this is because common use cases want to preserve `/`:

> The default for the safe arg is '/'. The character is reserved, but in
> typical usage the quote function is being called on a path where the
> existing slash characters are to be preserved.